# Flutter: Implement vibration in background

Tags: flutter

I want to implement the following use case:

*After the user clicks on a button the device should vibrate after X seconds **even if the device is locked or the app is not in the foreground.***

I already have the code in place to vibrate and for that I used the [vibration](https://pub.dev/packages/vibration) package. Now how do I make the device vibrate in the background?

I have seen suggestions like using the [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) to run this in the background but I am unsure if this is the easiest manner to handle this use case or if I am even able to access the vibration API from withhin the background service.

Can anyone offer advice for this use case?

Comment: That flutter_background_service or any other background service package wont help you if someone closes the app. Also these kind of background processes are really limited and the operating system can kill the background process anytime. This is because phones have really limited battery lifes

Comment: Are you trying to create some kind of alarm? I have never created an alarm in flutter but that is something that I would look into. For example https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus

Comment: I wanted to create a reminder for the user to begin his next exercise for my fitness app. I think an alarm fits my use case really well. Thank you ^^ Feel free to leave an answer so I can accept it, I used this package https://pub.dev/packages/alarm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of use case an alarm is more suitable. Background processes are not as reliable for time-specific actions because the operating system does battery optimization which restrict background activities. There are packages for creating alarms:

pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus

pub.dev/packages/alarm